# Формула-шаблон и её последующий просчёт

Tags: java, строки, парсер, математика, формулы

Всем добрый вечер! Кто нибудь может помочь, с такой задачкой... Есть шаблон формулы например всем известного дискриминанта `D=b^2-4ac` и последующий подсчёт корней (но это уже потом), и есть например строчка ввёдная юзером `6x^2-4x-75` как их совместить, то-есть сделать просчёт по формуле? Я не говорю "как сделать запил под одну формулу?", я хочу спросить как распарсить данный нам string хотя-бы на массив вида `[6x^2;-4x;-75]`, то-есть чтобы можно было сделать под разные другие формулы?

Comment: А такое `-6.00e3x^.3e-2-0.x^2-.0e0` на входе может быть?

Comment: Может, стоит парсить обычным сплитом по знакам-разделителям? То есть по плюсу или минусу. И в полученных строках уже определять, в какой степени там икс. Тогда и порядок не важен будет

Comment: @AlexanderZonov не ))) Что-то адекватное, максимум `(-pi)*x^2+ex-234`, но ещё можно в пример взять формулу из схемы горнера `45x^3+45.6x^2-x+56`

Comment: @PeterSamokhin у меня была такая идея, ещё была через регулярные выражения (но так как я их не умею делать, посчитал это плохой идеей :D), но я решил спросить может есть какие нибудь другие идеи или библиотеки какие нибудь, чтобы не изобретать велик

Comment: Что бы без велосипедов, смотрите в сторону генераторов лексических/ синтаксических анализаторов. bison, yacc и прочий крупный рогатый скот. Хотя приведенные вами формулы не особо сложно разобрать и самописным конечным автоматом

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F+%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F

Answer (score 0):

Задача решается так:

1. Определяемся с синтаксисом, то есть понимаем , что `^` знак возведения в степень, как трактуется знак умножения, скобки и проч.
2. Далее задаемся генератором/лексическим анализатором - [неполный список здесь](http://catalog.compilertools.net/lexparse.html)
3. Задаем нашу грамматику в терминах выбранного генератора (обычно задается в виде настроек)
4. Генерируем парсер на выбранном языке
5. Кастомизируем под себя и встраиваем в свой проект

Обычно парсер работает в 3 прохода:

1. Разбивка исходной строки на токены/лексемы
2. Генерация дерева инструкций (в соответствии с грамматикой и правилами приоритетов операций - в тупом варианте это как раз [польская инверсная запись](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C))
3. Исполнение инструкций (обычно рекурсивно или через стек)

P.S. Такое написание парсера, это стандартная курсовая 1 или 2-го курса буржуйского *Computer Science*. Для прогера среднего уровня агрессивности - это задачка на пару часов.